# "++++[++++>---<]>+.[--" what type of language or encoding is this?

Tags: cryptography

I was wondering

> ++++[++++>---<]>+.[-->+++<]>-.--.++++++++++++.-----------.+.--[--->+<]>-.>-[--->+<]>-.[---->+++++<]>-.+.++++++++++.+[---->+<]>+++.+.

What type of encoding it is?

Comment: ok understand! Actually i am noob here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), an [esoteric programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language), not an encoding type. Specifically that's a program that prints out a short string.

You can try it here: https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=IisrKytbKysrKz4tLS08XT4rLlstLT4rKys8XT4tLi0tLisrKysrKysrKysrKy4tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS4rLi0tWy0tLT4rPF0-LS4-LVstLS0-KzxdPi0uWy0tLS0-KysrKys8XT4tLisuKysrKysrKysrKy4rWy0tLS0-KzxdPisrKy4rLiIKCg$$